# Word for someone who is a mix of shy and deliberately obtuse in a slightly flirtatious way

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Searching for the right adjective to describe someone. She a mix of shy and deliberately obtuse in a slightly flirtatious way. Very calculated. Is purposely vague for the sake of trying to drum up interest. Not in a negative-connotation but more so in an friendly annoying way. Imagine someone coming to you to let you know they have terribly bad news with a smile on their face and then when you inquire about it - rather than tell you they change the topic to something totally different with the hopes that you continue to press for more information.

"Obtuse" seemed too unintentional and not calculated, "disingenuous" - was my closest fit but seemed too cold, "coy" - too playful... can't quite put my finger on it.

EX: Don't take her constant vagueness too personally, she's just being (insert adj).

EX: She is so ( ). Every time I try to peel back the layers on her we end up on a whole new tangent.

Comment: Sounds to me like you might want 'coquettish', but please be aware that I had to re-tag your question as a "single-word-request" because that's what you're looking for (a single word with a particular meaning" and we have specific rules about what details you need to provide for that sort of question.  If you hover over the new tag, you should be able to see what we'd like to have in a s-w-r question and then you can click the 'edit' link (below the question itself) to add the necessary bits.  Thanks, and welcome!

Comment: Thanks! I edited original post. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Why does it have to be one word? Is this for a poem where you have to fit the meter in just the right way?

Comment: recalcitrant, evasive, cagey. Tho I'd suspect that she just thinks she has to have an excuse to start a conversation and/or overthinks the interdiction.

Comment: @Mitch thanks! Doesn't need to be just one word ( this is actually my first question on here so still learning the rules etc) but in short, more than one word is okay!

Comment: @glen Gotta start somewhere! My point is that, though English has this great ability to provide a single word for some of the most obtuse complex concepts, sometimes a situation just doesn't have a single word to fit _exactly_ that idea. There will surely be one that encompasses you idea _and_ a whole bunch of other ideas. And there are surely a number of words together that hit exactly your idea. But there's never a guarantee that a single word will get your idea _and nothing more_.

Comment: @glen But of course, the single word that means what you want and more (of things that you don't necessarily want but are OK with) may be sufficient. This is a comment for anyone who comes on to ELU looking for an exact single word. Sometimes things are complex. You may want to say 'She is weird' (which could describe a whole bunch of other situations too. Or you may want to say 'She is shy and obtuse' (which may be the most accurate, but not a single word). Or you may want to reword entirely 'I don't get her. She is x,y,z,...'

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your contributions - Much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider ***sly***. It has connotations of being underhanded and playful.

> 1. Having or showing a cunning and deceitful nature.
>      *‘a **sly**, manipulative woman’*
>      <sub>**cunning**, crafty, clever, wily, artful, guileful, tricky, conniving, scheming, devious, designing, deceitful, duplicitous, dishonest, disingenuous, underhand, sneaky, untrustworthy</sub>
>
>    1.1 Showing in an insinuating way that one has some secret knowledge that may be harmful or embarrassing.
>      *‘he gave a **sly** grin’*
>      <sub>**roguish**, mischievous, impish, puckish, playful, teasing, naughty, wicked, waggish</sub>
>
>    1.2 (of an action) surreptitious.
>      *‘a **sly** sip of water’*
>      <sub>**surreptitious**, furtive, stealthy, covert, secret</sub>
>
> <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sly)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Consider the words below:

> Coquette /kɒˈkɛt/ - a flirtatious woman
>
> Minx - an impudent, cunning, or boldly flirtatious girl or young woman

Examples:

- The **little minx** knew exactly what she was doing and she actually enjoyed it. She sang to the bartender, who smiled widely, not daring to tell the **minx** to get off his counter.
- I don't know. I thought you were more of a **coquette**... not so ladylike. She would flirt with every man in the room and play the cold-hearted **coquette** in order to make him jealous and make his move.

Source: [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coquette)

If you are looking for an adjective, "coquettish" might work:

> She greeted him with a **coquettish** smile. Don't take her constant vagueness too personally, she's just being **coquettish**.

Comment: You need citations for your quotes otherwise it is plagiarism.

Comment: @Laurel you got it

Answer (score 1):

**Demure** can function this way. It can mean *actually* modest, or *affectedly* modest. And the ambiguity can be handy.

> 1 : RESERVED, MODEST
>   2 : affectedly modest, reserved, or serious : COY

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demure

Answer (score 1):

She [plays games](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+games).

> to play games (with one): To deliberately attempt to evade, deceive, or misinform one (about something) in order to manipulate them or achieve some desired outcome. *Quit playing games, Karen—I know that you're involved in this deal! The serial killer is playing games with the police, leaving false clues everywhere to muddy the investigation.*

Answer (score 0):

*Ditzy* , *dizzy* , and *bubbly* are sometimes used in this sense. Often a female, often blonde, but context has to make it clear that they are not just a dumb blonde, they are putting it on.

*Every time I try to peel back the layers on her we end up on a whole new tangent.*

Geometrically speaking, this is a very confusing metaphor! Anyway, here you seem to be thinking of *not as dumb as she looks* or perhaps *still waters run deep.*